# In WPF, building a UserControl with a Button and a Popup, and how to hide Popup when I click MenuItem in it?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, user-controls, popup

I building a UserControl named `MenuPopup`. And I use this control in project with MVVM.

It like this:

[image]
[image]

But now, I have no ideal to hide the Popup after click one MenuItem. If hide it by Menuitems' Click events, then how to binding command to ViewModel to handle business logic?

```
<!--MenuPopup.xaml-->
<UserControl
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:Microsoft_Windows_Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    x:Class="WpfApplication10.MenuPopup"
    x:Name="UserControl">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="ButtonFocusVisual">
            <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Rectangle Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ButtonNormalBackground" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
            <GradientStop Color="#F3F3F3" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#EBEBEB" Offset="0.5"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#DDDDDD" Offset="0.5"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#CDCDCD" Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonNormalBorder" Color="#FF707070"/>

        <Geometry x:Key="ArrowGraph">M 3,6 L 13,6 L 8,12 Z</Geometry>
        <Geometry x:Key="LineGraph" >M 12.3,7 L 9,11</Geometry>

        <Style x:Key="ArrowMenuButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource ButtonFocusVisual}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#00FFFFFF"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFFFFFFF"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="1"/>
                            <Path x:Name="ArrowPath" Data="{StaticResource ArrowGraph}" Fill="#FFFFFFFF"/>
                            <Path x:Name="LinePath" Data="{StaticResource LineGraph}" Fill="#FFD5D5D5" />
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true"/>
                            <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="true"/>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ADADAD"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Background"  Value="#FF219266"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF167559"/>
                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="LinePath" Value="#FF1E7B57"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Background"  Value="#FF219266"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF7ABEA3"/>
                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="LinePath" Value="#FF1E7B57"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid>
            <Button x:Name="MenuButton" Click="MenuButton_Click" Content="" Width="16" Height="16" BorderThickness="0" Padding="0" Style="{DynamicResource ArrowMenuButtonStyle}" />
            <Popup x:Name="MenuButtonPopup" StaysOpen="False" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=MenuButton}" >
                <Grid>
                    <Border Background="White">
                        <StackPanel >
                            <MenuItem Header="XX1" />
                            <MenuItem Header="XX2" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </Popup>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

.

```
// MenuPopup.xaml.cs
namespace WpfApplication10
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MenuPopup.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MenuPopup : UserControl
    {

        public MenuPopup()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void MenuButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MenuButtonPopup.IsOpen = true;
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:**

Now, I use both click event(which button's) and command. The click event handler in code-behind file, and the command in ViewModel.

```
<!--parts in MenuPopup.xaml -->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Button x:Name="MenuButton" Click="MenuButton_Click" Content="" Width="16" Height="16" BorderThickness="0" Padding="0" Style="{DynamicResource ArrowMenuButtonStyle}" />
    <Popup x:Name="MenuButtonPopup" StaysOpen="False" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=MenuButton}" >
        <Grid>
            <Border Background="White">
                <StackPanel >
                    <MenuItem Header="XX1" Click="MenuItem_Click" Command="{Binding IncreaseCommand}"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="XX2" Click="MenuItem_Click" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </Popup>
</Grid>
```

.

```
// MenuPopup.xaml.cs
namespace WpfApplication10
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MenuPopup.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MenuPopup : UserControl
    {

        public MenuPopup()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void MenuButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MenuButtonPopup.IsOpen = true;
        }

        private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MenuButtonPopup.IsOpen = false;
        }
    }
}
```

.

```
// MainViewModel.cs
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;

namespace WpfApplication10.ViewModel
{
    public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            IncreaseCommand = new RelayCommand(() => ++Cnt);
        }

        private int cnt = 0;
        public int Cnt
        {
            get { return cnt; }
            set { cnt = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Cnt"); }
        }

        private RelayCommand increaseCommand;
        public RelayCommand IncreaseCommand { get; private set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use `Command Binding` to route the event to the view model, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: oh, I should have a try to use a click event handler and commandbinding.

Comment: I use both click event and command, it works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have bool property on your viewmodel as IsPopupOpen and bind Popup.IsOpen to this property. Now bind your button Command to the command defined in ViewModel and in your commandhandler set IsPopupOpen to false.

Thanks

Comment: I just think that hiding popup may be handled in View layer. If my opinion is wrong, please tell me, I'm just a newbie.

Comment: are you using MVVM i.e do you have ViewModel backing your view(userControl)?

Comment: With MVVM, I use Commond binding buttons in UserControl to MainViewModel(because the UserControl used in Master Interface) and handle some business logic. Should I create a specialized ViewModel to used for the UserControl?

Comment: That is what I am saying you can have one more property in MainViewModel and bind it to IsPopupOpen and in your command handler of button command set IsPopupOpen to false. Set binding mode as two way